# Accessing the WPF element in parent window from the user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a custom menu control in the main window of my WPF application. In main window, I have a frame. I want to change the page in this frame based on the selection in the custom menu control. Below is the code I tried.

```
    Private Sub NominationMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim parentWindow As Window
    parentWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow
    parentWindow.MainFrame.Navigate(New NominationSearch)
End Sub
```

I know that I can't directly access "MainFrame" control using the "parentWindow" object. How do I rewrite the last line to get a reference to the existing frame object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not appropriate for `UserControl` to manipulate it's parent. You should let your `MainWindow` to listen for `NominationMenuItem` changes via events and then `MainWindow` itself do the navigation.

So first you need to define an event in your `UserControl`:

```
Public Event NominationMenuItemChanged As RoutedEventHandler

Private Sub NominationMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent NominationMenuItemChanged(Me, New RoutedEventArgs())
End Sub
```

And then listen to this event in your `MainWindow`:

```
Public Sub MainWindow()
    AddHandler MyUserControl.NominationMenuItemChanged, AddressOf UC_NominationMenuItemChanged
End Sub

Private Sub UC_NominationMenuItemChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MainFrame.Navigate(MyUserControl.NominationSearch)
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, let me give it a try. BTW, why is it not appropriate to manipulate parent from the user control?

Edit: Received an error.

Comment: Error 1 'Public Sub New()' in designer-generated type 'SMS.MainWindow' should call InitializeComponent method. D:\Documents\Office Work\VPS - SMS\Development\SMS\SMS\MainWindow.xaml.vb 2 16 SMS

Comment: Ok, changed "new" to "mainwindow". So, that works. But, after the event is raised from the user control, mainwindow does not read the event.

Comment: does the debugger hit this line `RaiseEvent NominationMenuItemChanged(Me, New RoutedEventArgs())`?

Comment: ok, done. Created an event for the mainwindow_loaded. Added handler in there, instead of "Sub New". Now, it works wonderfully. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: You are welcome, btw, to answer your question in the first comment: if a `UserControl` knows it's parent, then it's not a `UserControl` anymore and it should be defined inside that specific parent control. A `UserControl` meant to be placed inside any parent control.